# Filter rows on multiple fields in where

Tags: sql, postgresql, filter, case, where-clause

I have a table with Mutations in my Postgres (Version 10) Database.

If i create i new user i get one row for each attribute that is updated.
For the enduser i only want to present the name + firstname for the user that has been added and not like 40 other attributes.

It's already a pretty complex query that i have and now i want to filter out the other attributes when a user is created.

Here is a very simple fiddle of my problem: [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1a297/1)

Here is what i want my output to look like: I want to concat the name + first name in 1 row and don't show the other attributes on Persons Created.

```
userid table1   did execution_date  change_type attr    value_old      value_new
    1   Persons 1   2021-01-01        Create    Name     null           Dan White
    2   Persons 4   2021-01-01        Update    Email    old@email.com  new@email.com
    3   User    5   2021-01-03        Update    Username  abc           rocky
    4   Deparm  6   2021-01-02        Delete    Code      01            null
```

I don't know a good way to add this part of filter into my query..

Comment: How are the fiddle and your question related? You talk about `name + firstname`, there's no such thing in the fiddle

Comment: oh no, somehow all my sample data in fiddle has been deleted. Have to make new ones

Comment: @HoneyBadger Now the fiddle works